# AngularJS controller can not inject resolver

Tags: angularjs, controller

Please see this [fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/VmqcLRSu7viRgl67MKZ2?p=preview)

I want to inject resolver into the AngularJS controller but not working. The error message is `Unknown provider: urlParasProvider <- urlParas <- MyController`

Any suggestions, thanks!

```
function config($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/abc',{
        controller: 'MyController',
        resolve: {
            urlParas : function(){
                // return $location.absUrl();
                return 'abc';
            }
        }
      })
      .otherwise({
        controller: 'MyController',
        resolve: {

            urlParas : function(){
                // return $location.absUrl();
                return 'abc';
            }

        }
      });
}

myApp.$inject = ['$scope','urlParas'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the controller is being instantiated by the`ng-controller` directive:

> ```
> ERRONEOUS
>   <body ng-controller="MyController">
>     <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
>     <h3>{{text}}</h3>
>   </body>
> ```

The `ng-controller` directive does not have access to resolver locals.

The `$compile` service instantiates the `ng-controller` directive and its controller without regard to the routing tables.

From the Docs:

> #### `$compile` DDO property - `controller`
>
> Controller constructor function. The **controller is instantiated** before the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior.
>
> The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:
>
> - `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
> - `$element` - Current element
> - `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
> - `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope
>
> [— AngularJS $compile Service Comprehensive Directive API - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

---

> Thanks! I tried to remove ng-controller="MyController" but not working,

Put the template in the route definition:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/abc',{
    controller: 'MyController',
    template: `
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <h3>{{text}}</h3>
    `,
    resolve: {
        urlParas : function(){
            // return $location.absUrl();
            return 'abc';
        }
    }
  })
```

And instantiate it with the [ng-view directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView):

```
  <body   ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶=̶"̶M̶y̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶"̶ >
    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
  </body>
```

The `ng-view` directive uses the routing tables to instantaiate the proper template and proper controller. It invokes the resolver functions and injects them as locals into the specified controller.

From the Docs:

> ### `$route.current.locals`:
>
> A map of locals which is used by [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service for **controller instantiation**. The `locals` contain the resolved values of the `resolve` map. Additionally the `locals` also contain:
>
> - `$scope` - The current route scope.
> - `$template` - The current route template HTML.
>
> The `locals` will be assigned to the route scope's `$resolve` property. You can override the property name, using `resolveAs` in the route definition.
>
> [— AngularJS ngRoute $route API Reference - current property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#current)

#### The Controller

```
app.controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope','urlParas']; 

function MyController($scope,urlParas){

  $scope.text = 'Sophia';

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to remove `ng-controller="MyController"` but not working, please see this fiddle https://plnkr.co/edit/atHri8

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why `The ng-controller directive does not have access to resolver locals.`?

Comment: With the `ng-controller` directive, the `$compile` service instantiates the controller. With the `ng-view` directive, the `$route` provider instantiates the controller after invoking the resolver functions. See update to the answer.